# How to view Pyserial data flow

Tags: windows-7, python-2.7, serial-port, arduino, pyserial

I am a beginner to pyserial. I have written the code from the internet:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(0)  # open first serial port
print ser.portstr       # check which port was really used
ser.write("hello")      # write a string
ser.close()
```

The program ran without any error and displayed an output "COM 7". I am running the code on my HP Pavilion Laptop with no visual COM ports on the system hardware (but in device manager it lists 6 COM ports). I would like to know, where did the string "hello" went which i wrote in the code and how can I 'virtually view' the data flow from system to any device connected ? 
Also, if I connect the device to one of my USB port on my laptop will the data (in this case string "hello") be transferred to the device.

Comment: Cmon guys any answers please..!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with it, but I think the Portmon tool might be able to help.  It monitors the status and activity of parallel and serial ports on Windows machines.

[Portmon for Windows v3.03](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx)